# Issue on Setting Position Absolute in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [this Demo](http://www.bootply.com/hrw26lbdPz) and let me know why I am not able to set up an absolute position on first row?

Thanks

```
html, body { height: 100%;  }
.element{ position:absolute; top:0; }
.one{height:500px; background-color:red;}
.two{height:500px; background-color:blue;}

<div class="container">

<div class="row fixed-top">This mUst be absolute</div>

<div class="row one"></div>

<div class="row two"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean you need element fixed to top. If yes, try to add

```
.fixed-top  { position:fixed; top:0; }
```

Comment: Thanks yuyokk this is working now but can you please let me know how dynamically set up a size for `.fixed-top ` >

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by saying 'dynamically' set up a size. As far as I know <div> tag gets a height of the inner content and 100% width by default as it is a block element

Comment: I mean I need to always display the `.one` under the `.fixed-top` no matter what size of the `.fixed-top`  may be1

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible with CSS only. You need to set padding-top on body element equal to the height of fixed-top.

Comment: you mean I have to use javascript on here?

Comment: Technically what I have to do is generating a layout like [This Webste](http://demo.stylishthemes.co/colibri/) as you can see the image stays on the fixed position and the other layers overlay on it on scroll

Comment: i think what you are trying to achieve is known as 'parallax'. e.g http://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/ it's not the same as just setting an element as fixed top. Sorry but i'm not familiar with this technique.